# is it possible to getElementsByClassName that only selects <input> tags?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have html code wherein the same class name is mapped to multiple HTML elements. Out of which I want only to get the value of "input" elements. Below is the sample code, please suggest how to get the value of "input" elements with the class name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="example">Element1</div>
        <div class="example">Element2</div>
        <input class="example" value="input1"/>
        <input class="example" value="input2"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried with below script, but document.getElementsByClassName("example") will return collection of "example" class name including "div" elements. I just need "input" element values.

```
<script>
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
collection[0].value = "Hello World!";
</script>
```

Comment: There ***has*** to be a previous version of this question. See MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll For your use case, `document.querySelector("input.example").value = "Hello world!";`

Comment: This is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425154/question-closed-was-my-explanation-poor-or-is-it-an-xy-problem). The Y being "getElementByClassName" since *as evidenced by its very name* it gives you elements by their class name. Not by their type or any other criteria. You're probably looking for either post-processing the list or using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which is far more flexible in what it returns.